# How to import SimpleMDE in ES6

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, markdown, simplemde

I am using [SimpleMDE](https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor/) in my Angular project which is using Webpack/ES6,

After install simplemde by npm:

`npm install --save simplemde`

When I import it in file by:

`import * as SimpleMDE from 'simplemde/src/js/simplemde';`

or

`import * as SimpleMDE from 'simplemde';`

or

`import SimpleMDE from 'simplemde';`

And use `new SimpleMDE(options)`, and get error in Chrome console.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: SimpleMDE is not defined`

Comment: Did you try to save it in your devDependencies? with npm i --save-dev simplemde ?

Comment: @DomeTune that would not do anything whatsoever other than write the dependency entry in package json under a different key.

Comment: That is strange. The last one is the correct way to import a module like this since the file they make public has `module.exports = SimpleMDE`, meaning you'd want to import it as a default. It's strange that you'd get the not defined error. When you say you get the error in the console, you don't mean after putting a debugger right? You literally tried writing `new SimpleMDE(options)` and it threw an error?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @Drew not yet. Currently my frontent stack is moved to Angular 2, there are some Angular 2 component for SimpleMDE. But I do not use it in projects now.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `import * as SimpleMDE from "SimpleMDE";`?

Notice the case sensitivity in the name "**S**imple**MDE**". The issue might be tied to the OS - Linux typically cares much more about case sensitivity than Windows.

I've tried it on a Windows machine and `new SimpleMDE(options)` was available to me.